# CodeIgniter session issue on Opera and Safari

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, safari, opera

I am using **codeigniter 1.7.2.**

In my web app after logging out, on clicking the back button of the browser the page is reloaded in the logged in page.

This issue is occuring on **Opera** and **Safari** only.
I have disabled cache using meta, but that doesn't help. :(

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-STORE" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-STORE" />
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how you disabled cache using meta?

Browsers use a separate caching-mechanism for browser history. Even if you disabled the cache a browser may still store a page for the browser history. The `Cache-Control: no-store` header should prevent storing pages at all. The best way to send this header is using PHP instead of relying on meta-elements:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
```

Also see: [What is Cacheable](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1,) for the difference between `Cache-Control: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-store`

*Update:* This doesn't work in Opera, it works at least in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: but header("Cache-Control: no-store"); is also not working :(

Comment: Ah, I just tested it and it seems Opera always caches pages used for it's history. More information on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866826/how-do-i-stop-opera-from-caching-a-page

Comment: but still, i didn't get a solution,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the only way to prevent Opera from using cache on history navigation (back/forward button) is to serve the page **over https** with **Cache-control: must-revalidate** header.

Comment: We're working on proposals to fix this problem, for example: http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-pettersen-cache-context-05.txt
An actual implementation is probably some time away - pending further discussion of the proposal.