# Disable browser 'Back' button after logout?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

I am using python with django i want redirect users to login page when he clicks back button after logout. How to achieve this? where to write the code?

To test whether django admin handles this..i logged into django admin..logged out and then hit back button and i am able to see the previous page. Why django admin does not handle this.

This is the ccode for logout in django admin:

```
def logout(request):
  """
 Removes the authenticated user's ID from the request and flushes their
 session data.
 """
 request.session.flush()
 if hasattr(request, 'user'):
     from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
     request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
def func()
  #some code
  return
```

This will force the browser to make request to server.

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari 13.0.3 (Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.1)

Answer (score 9):

You may find you need to use @cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True) in chrome to fully stop any back button viewing.

The key thing being no_store for chrome as I found here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625046/django-login-required-views-still-show-when-users-are-logged-out-by-going-back)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you can the admin page, after you logged out and hit back is, that you don't see the real page. Rather you see a *copy* of it that is in your browser cache.

Try this:

1. go to any admin page
2. click "Logout"
3. hit the "Back" button in your browser
4. press F5 or click "Refresh" in your browser.

Now you will be redirected to the login page of the admin backend.

Comment: The code i have pasted is the django.contrib.auth.logout. Its not my own code..i am using django admin only. This problem exists in django admin.

Comment: Oh dear...*now* I understand what you are asking. I will rewrite my answer.

Comment: i know that no requests will be sent to server wen back button is clicked..but still i dont want users to see the page like google does

Comment: Ok, i think here is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510151/can-i-disable-ff3-back-button-cache

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Digital Cake's answer! This solved the problem of backing up into cached pages after logout on FireFox as well.  I tried:

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)

on my views with no luck.  Per Digital Cake, tried:

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)

and now Firefox backs up to the login screen.

Comment: @GeorgeK It does work! Try placing the decorator on the login view as well.

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari 13.0.3 (Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.1)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but the accepted answer did not work for me. i faced the same problem (using django 1.8 & Chrome)

Finally, I found the solution from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) (django 1.7 or later). This will work for sure.

Just see the code below

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def myview(request):
    return HttpResponse(render(request,'path_to_your_view.html'))
```

`@login_required` decorator is used to handle the issue. You can check more in doc

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari 13.0.3 (Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.1)

Answer (score 1):

This is a cache problem.

You can use cache_control decorator to force no cache on views:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
def func()
  # some code
  return
```

This will force the browser to make a request to the server.

More about [cache_control](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what kind of authentication system you are using. If u are using some kind of own impl, you could write own `Middleware` class that redirects unathenticated users to login page.

If you are using some lib, check its docs how it handles request to secured pages from unauthenticated users.