# Django @login_required views still show when users are logged out by going back in history on Chrome

Tags: django, caching, google-chrome, login-required

::Edit::

`@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)` FTW!!!!!

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate did the trick. It took going to a few IRC chans and looking around but finally I got it to work.

::EDIT::

I have a view where I'm setting @login_required on it and its secure for the most part, but if you have looked at the view then logout and just hit the back button in your browser you can view the content again with out being asked to login. Though if you refresh the page the server with will redirect you.

My suspension is its a cache issue where maybe I need to tell chrome not to store it in the history.

if you view a invoice for example then logout you can view the invoice again by selecting that page in your back history.

I have tried this issue o firefox with no problem. firefox asks for you to log back end so it must be a browser issue.

Comment: Whether or not the page shows up in the browser's history has nothing to do with `login_required`. That's going to show up regardless. However the page should not load as if the user was logged in when they are not. If that's happening, that's an entirely different issue.

Comment: Sorry for not being more knowledgeable about issue. I described it as best as I understood the issue. Regardless I feel that upon hitting the back button the content should not be view able if the user is no longer logged in, of which is not a problem with firefox.

Comment: There is very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923027/disble-back-buttonon-browser-after-logout-in-django

Comment: Did you edit this question to put the answer into the question? Painful. Why not just edit it to be clear, and let the accepted answer stand as the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this is cache problem.

You can use `cache_control` decorator to force no cache on views[1]:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
def func()
  #some code
  return
```

You should also write your own decorator that replaces `@login_required` so that you don't need to use both on every page.

[1] [Disable browser 'Back' button after logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923027/disble-back-buttonon-browser-after-logout-in-django)

Comment: So I have checked that there is indeed "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" in the header but its still showing the page regardless.

thats with the use of 
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
and I have tried 
@never_cache

Comment: very close, thanks for the help though.   
I found that @cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True) worked.

Comment: Edited the answer as Digital Cake suggested

Comment: Very helpful, but I wonder about `You should also write your own decorator that replaces @login_required so that you don't need to use both on every page.` While it may give a little bit of DRY, it arguably would make for less readable code. Seems very easy to have two little decorators. Have you seen this done, or done it yourself (i.e., wrapped the two decorators into one)? I'd be very curious to see the simplest code for doing it.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is caused by a feature in **Webkit** browsers unofficially called **Page Cache**, also known as the back/forward cache. It controls what happens to previous pages in the current browsing session. Webkit does something special in that it "suspends" previous pages. It's as if the previous page is hidden in another tab; clicking the back button is like bringing the tab into the foreground. The page is still there just as it was. This means no network request is made and therefore your server logic is never touched.

You'll see this behavior in Safari as well as Chrome. Look at the Network Inspector [panel](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html) and watch the network traffic when you click *back* to a page. At a glance it looks like a request was made. Safari doesn't help dispel the notion that no request was actually made. Chrome is more polite and tells you the page was loaded "(from cache)". In Chrome, look at the *size* column or click the request and look at the *Status Code* in the *Headers* tab. Of course the other indicator is how long the 'request' took in the *Timeline* (probably 0ms).

That explains the behavior...now how to get around it. The best solution may just be a **reminder on the logout page** to close the browser window.

You've correctly determined that there's nothing you can do on the Django side. The cache decorators won't help you. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a canonical answer to preventing Page Cache from stashing a page. It also seems to be a feature in flux, so a solution now may just be a hack that won't work on later versions of Webkit. Or Firefox may create a similar feature with different implementation.

Serving your site over HTTPS with `cache-control: no-store` or `cache-control: no-cache` may do it but it's heavy handed for sure. One possible hack would be to set an `unload/onunload` event handler.

Read more about Page Cache behavior and the unload hack suggestion on [these](http://www.webkit.org/blog/427/webkit-page-cache-i-the-basics/) [two](http://www.webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/) Surfin' Safari articles.

**UPDATE** - @DigitalCake found that `Cache-Control:no-store` has some effect. In Django, this is accomplished with `@cache_control(no_store=True)` decorating the view. `no store` *works* in Chrome (v17.0.963.66) - the page is not stashed in Page Cache and the back button causes a network request. `no store` does *not work* in Safari (v5.1.3). This shows that even across Webkit browsers Page Cache is implemented differently. It demonstrates also the point that current work arounds are likely to be temporary hacks.

Comment: It sucks because there is "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" the header already.

Comment: The back/forward page cache isn't a *real* cache - it's just suspending the page - so it doesn't follow cache control rules.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it worked for me.

I had put both cashe control and login required.

Here is the example

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
@login_required(login_url='login')
def myview(request):
   return HttpResponse(render(request,'path_to_your_view.html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

March 2020 update: Adding to the accepted answer, the Django 3.0 docs show a `never_cache` decorator.

It adds a `Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private` header to the response.