# Django - LogoutView - cache_control - browser's back button has the logged out user's cache

Tags: python, django, browser, browser-cache, cache-control

Django 2.1.7

This is for a simple blog with homepage (post list view), post detail view, and profile (post list view)

When a user logs out, `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`  redirects the user to the homepage.

**However, when the user clicks the browser's back button, the previous page still shows all the logged out user's data. When I reload the page, it clears the cache.**

when the user's logged in, shows username]

[image: when the user's logged in, shows username]

when the user's logged out, shows 'login'

[image: when the user's logged out, shows 'login']

I found a similar question and their answer was to use the cache_control decorator.
[Django - User re-entering session by clicking browser back button after logging out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000981/django-user-re-entering-session-by-clicking-browser-back-button-after-logging)

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
@login_required
```

- Would I have to add these decorators to every single view?
- I do not want the `@login_required` decorator. AnonymousUsers should be able to view all pages without logging in.

What's the best way to do this? Similar to Twitter's logout flow. (user logs out -> login page -> back button -> previous page but reloaded)

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

Comment: Likely Django does not send the previous page: this is just the browser that stored the old one and rerenders it. So it does not load "actual" data, it simply displays the "old page".

Comment: Yes, understood. Trying to figure out a workaround for this. I do not want the data from the 'old page' to show if the user clicks the browser's back button. Also seems to be a security risk. I'm kind of surprised it's hard to find an answer on SO for this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your views function on the login definition:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
       
       #ure....code....here
```

Every time the session expires the user is forced to log out and then after authenticating and logging in to the page the user will visit only authorized contents.

If you use `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` on your HTML page you can restrict them.

Comment: 'u' and 'ure' are *not* words! 'You' and 'your' are, though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).