# Site shows data after logout when clicks back button (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, logout

Whenever i logout from my Django site , when i press browser's back button browser shows previous cached data .I need to clear all site data when logging out. Is there a way using JavaScript or something?

I've tried

`@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, max_age=0)`

but i only need to clear when user logs out . is there any solution except i provided above one?

Comment: You can check how to disable browser back button using js/jquery  though its not the right/ grantee  in every case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923027/disable-browser-back-button-after-logout
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-can-i-stop-the-browser-back-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This can't done as the browser didn't request a new request, the page was rendered from the browser's cache using back/forward cache. You can read more about it from [here](https://web.dev/articles/bfcache)

You can cancel this behaviour in user-critical pages by the following js code

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event) => {
   if (event.persisted && !document.cookie.match(/sessionid/)) {
   // Force a reload if the user has logged out.
    location.reload();
  }
});
```